# PyMC3 plots.traceplot in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, pymc3, arviz

Is there something extra I need to do to show my PyMC3  `plots.traceplot` results in PyCharm?  I just discovered that I need a `print()` statement around `pm.summary()`. so I'm wondering if there is another function for the plots.  Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyMC3 uses [ArviZ](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/index.html) for plotting (as well as for statistics and summary such as `summary`) which at the same time, relies on either matplotlib of Bokeh. To be able to call several plotting commands and customize the figures, both libraries require to call a command at the end to finish figure creation and show the generated plot. In matplotlib's case, it's `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` and in Bokeh's case it's `bokeh.plotting.show(plot)`.

When using ArviZ in an interactive manner (and therefore barely customizing ArviZ generated plots), ArviZ can be configured to automatically show all generated plots by doing:

```
import arviz as az
az.rcParams["plot.matplotlib.show"] = True  # bokeh plots are automatically shown by default
```

This will make `pm.traceplot` automatically show the plot straight away. If this is a too general setting, there is also the option of using `pm.traceplot(..., show=True)` on a per plot basis.

Comment: This is the solution I needed!  The plots are working beautifully :) Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Glad it was useful :)